# Regex Negative Lookahead With Multiple Strings

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to exclude specific strings from a query:

Using this blog post here:
https://blog.codinghorror.com/excluding-matches-with-regular-expressions/

I've found that the following works fine for one string (in this case, Fox):

```
(?!Fox\b)\b\w+
```

However, I want to add in OR conditions and exclude three strings.

Comment: `(?!Fox|Wolf|Bear)`

Comment: Also, if you want to exclude only specific words (and not words that start with `Fox` append `\b` to the end of the negative lookahead like so `\b(?!(?:Fox|Wolf|Bear)\b)\w+`. It'll prevent the word `Fox` but allow `Foxtrot`

Comment: OP just missed the backslashes. @ctwheels, I can't find a dupe, you may post an answer.

Comment: What would I need to do if one of the words to exclude is actually two words with a space in between e.g. "fox trot"?

Comment: @JimBob117 What is your regex flavor? What is the programming language? Show the code. Next time you ask via a comment, please add `@`+username

Comment: looks weird but works for me: `(?!(.*(Fox\b)))(?!(.*(Bear\b)))(?!(.*(Wolf\b)))\b\w+`